# Using ASP.NET Razor Edit Data Page in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, razor

i have some problem here with Edit Data Using ASP.NET Razor in WebMatrix 
i write this code for edit a data using the Update command but unfortunately it doesnt work :s :s

Razor code :

```
    @{
      {
            var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%@1%'";
    db.Execute(query,"refuser", userId);
 }
    }
```

the html code :

```
    <form action="responsable.cshtml" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="saadwafqui" />
    <input type="submit" value="Oui" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I would recommend you fixing this. Also you seem to be using some `IsPost` variable which is not quite clear where is being defined.

Example:

```
@{
    var userId = Request["userid"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%' + @1 + '%'";
    db.Execute(query, "refuser", userId);
}
```

Notice the syntax around the LIKE clause:

```
LIKE '%' + @1 + '%'
```

This will match all records that have `UserId` in the middle. If you wanted to match only records that the UserId starts with the value in the request:

```
LIKE '%' + @1
```

and if you wanted exact match simply use the `=` operator instead of a LIKE clause.

Also your markup looks completely broken. There's no `window.location` attribute. Maybe you meant something like this:

```
<form action="responsable.cshtml" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="saadwafqui" />
    <input type="submit" value="Oui" /> 
</form>
```

or with a GET request if you prefer:

```
<form action="responsable.cshtml" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="saadwafqui" />
    <input type="submit" value="Oui" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: tnnnnnnnks dudde fr your help but it does not working :s look to what happend when i execute the page :
http://data.imagup.com/11/1144944948.PNG
here is the data base : 
http://data.imagup.com/12/1144945047.PNG

Comment: the problem of the error in the image that i show it to u is solved but it steel des'nt update tha commande in the data :s

Comment: @user1233875, that's because the UserID in your database value is `SaadWafqui` and you are sending `saadwafqui` as parameter so the LIKE clause doesn't find any matching records.

Comment: tnkssss my bro fr the notice of the UserId parameter :)
it works well like this @{
    var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'refuser' WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query);
}